# Django - Filtering foreign keys using related properties

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to filter a table in django based on the selected category. The category field is equivalent to name.

I can't wrap my head around filtering all the blogposts which link to that certain category id.

I currently use this:
`category_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(category=cats).order_by('-published')`
Which I could use without there being any foreign key. I am passing the string variable into the path

How could I make this more efficient and use the foreign key that relates the table..
Something like this:
`category_posts = Blogpost.objects.filter(category__category__contains=cat)`

I don't know if I am complicating things, just confused

The following are the 2 tables available:

```
name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('category', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('summary', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('slug', models.CharField(default=1, max_length=200)),
            ],
```

```
name='Blogpost',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
                ('published', models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 8, 20, 49, 14, 897634), verbose_name='date published')),
                ('slug', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('category', models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_DEFAULT, to='blogposts.Category', verbose_name='Category')),
            ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example would work if `cat` was a string, and return all blogposts that point to any category that has cat in the name.

```
category_posts = Blogpost.objects.filter(category__category__contains="cat")
```

If you want to filter a specific category, e.g.

```
cat = Category.objects.get(category="cat")
```

then you can do with with:

```
BlogPost.objects.filter(category=cat)
```

In terms of design, it might be more clear to call the char field that stores category name as simply "name". Then the very first query would look like `BlogPost.objects.filter(category__name__contains="cat")` and the second `cat = Category.objects.get(name="cat")`.